# LyX Style, that renders like a \paragraph command?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

In the layout/module file format of LyX, is there any method to produce a paragraph style, that renders and exports like

```
\paragraph{title}
content...
```

The purpose would be to create layouts, where `\paragraph`s look as they would in the printed document.

I am aware, that a `Style Paragraph` exists by default, but I am specifically looking for making the interface more WYSIWYG-like, in order to improve visual clarity. When deeply nested elements occur, especially beyond `secnumdepth`, it is hard to tell for the formatting if an element is on a higher or lower nesting level. (Added as clarification after [Torbjørn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457608/34769))

---

LyX "Style" definitions have an option

```
LabelType manual
```

A style

```
Style CustomParagraph
  Category Sectioning
  LabelType manual
  LatexType command
  LatexName paragraphx
  LabelFont
    Series bold
  EndFont
  LeftDelim "<br/>"
  RightDelim "<br/>"
  Preamble
    \newcommand\paragraphx[1][]{\paragraph{#1}}
  EndPreamble
End
```

would render the words until the first space bold (non-breaking spaces can be used to render multiple words bold), and export as

```
\paragraphx[{title}]{
content...
}
```

While this works, it is ugly. I much rather would have the style exported as

```
\paragraph{title}
content...
```

and avoid the auxiliary command `\paragraphx[]{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the document class, there should be a Paragraph style by default, is there anything wrong with that?

(The screenshots are from an older version of LyX, as that is what I had available, but I'd expect the same in the latest version.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that the OP want to see a more WYSIWYG LyX screen, with "**foobar** stuff" in the same line, since in this way will be showed in the PDF in standard classes, whereas as you showed, by default show the paragraphs just like  a `\subsubsection*`

Comment: Well,  as far I can see there are a little more space after a `\subsubsection*` that after a `\paragraph`, but certainly it could be a mess work with several of these levels without check everytime the outline pane.

Comment: @Fran I see, you're probably right. I'll leave it for now, but will delete it later if the OP thinks it's worthless.

Comment: It's fine to keep the answer; I should have clarified that I know about the default paragraph style. But @Fran is right, I am mostly looking to make sectioning more WYSIWYG, as the defaults can result in inconvinient visual clutter. This is especially true for flex insets.